# How to stop a program when a key is pressed in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pynput

I have a program that is an endless loop that prints "program running" every 5 seconds and I want to stop it when I press the end key.

So I created a key listener that returns false if the end key is pressed. That should work if I won't have the endless loop. And I want it to work even when I'm in the endless loop.

Here's my code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
def on_press(key):
    print key
    if key == keyboard.Key.end:
        print 'end pressed'
        return False        
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    while True:
        print 'program running'
        time.sleep(5)
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time

break_program = False
def on_press(key):
    global break_program
    print (key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.end:
        print ('end pressed')
        break_program = True
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    while break_program == False:
        print ('program running')
        time.sleep(5)
    listener.join()
```

Comment: that's actually so easy and simple! thank you for reminding me how dumb I am!

Comment: does that mean ```listener.join()``` is called while the ```while``` loop is running?
Also, I got ```Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'break_program' is not defined```

Comment: no, it is outside of while loop.

Comment: break_program is a global variable in the code snippet i shared. show me your module please.